# Would Thumb-2 ARM-Core Micros From Different Manufacturers Have Same Codesize?

Tags: arm, thumb, cortex-a8, cortex-m

Comparing two Thumb-2 micros from two different manufacturers. One's a Cortex M3, one's an A5. Are they guaranteed to compile a particular piece of code to the same codesize?

Comment: it all depends on the compiler.  There are different variants of thumb2 extensions and depending on if and what variant you have told the compiler to use, that is what it will use.  It is possible the compiler has architecture specific if-then-elses in its code generation.  The simple answer is to "just try it" then ask stack overflow, "why is this different"  or "why isnt this different"

Comment: the chip vendors get their cores from arm, note that arm has different versions of the same core, so there may be two or three cortex-m3 cores at this point.  and IF there is a need for code changes between them (some instruction doesnt work or some instruction sequence) and IF the compiler knows, that and so on.

Comment: Also you will never have a guarantee that different compilers will generate the same output from the same input for the same target.  Even different versions of the same compiler wont have that guarantee, nor will different builds of the same compiler same version, if the builds have different options.  Using the word guaranteed in your question almost automatically results in a NO, no guarantees.

Comment: So if I AM using the same compiler, I could expect that any differences would be minimal (if not non-existant)?

Comment: depends on the command lines you use.  If there is a desire to have the same compiled code on two platforms then just compile that object one time and link it into either project (well if it will let you do that).  Otherwise you need to somehow examine the two compiler outputs to verify the same code was generated.  Linking can make some modifications for items outside that code, so any functions in another file/object are resolved at link time so the final linked output may vary for the platforms but it will be subtle.

Comment: What "particular pice of code" - a full application, or a simple piece of arithmetic in an isolated source file? What "code size" - that of the generated instruction sequences, or that of the entire set of software that will be executing on the target? The Cortex-A5 has caches and an MMU, will probably be running a full operating system with shared libraries. The Cortex-M3 has a completely different exception model and will often run a statically linked rtos image. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

so here goes

fun.c

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int x )
{
    return(x);
}
```

addimm.c

```
extern unsigned int fun ( unsigned int );
unsigned int addimm ( unsigned int x )
{
    return(fun(x)+0x123);
}
```

for demonstration purposes building for bare metal, not really a functional program but it compiles clean and demonstrates what I intend to demonstrate.

arm instructions

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall  -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding -mcpu=cortex-a5 -march=armv7-a -c addimm.c -o addimma.o
```

disassembly of the object, not linked

```
00000000 <addimm>:
   0:   e92d4008    push    {r3, lr}
   4:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <fun>
   8:   e2800e12    add r0, r0, #288    ; 0x120
   c:   e2800003    add r0, r0, #3
  10:   e8bd8008    pop {r3, pc}
```

thumb generic (armv4 or v5 whatever the default was for this compiler build)

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall  -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding -mthumb -c addimm.c -o addimmt.o

00000000 <addimm>:
   0:   b508        push    {r3, lr}
   2:   f7ff fffe   bl  0 <fun>
   6:   3024        adds    r0, #36 ; 0x24
   8:   30ff        adds    r0, #255    ; 0xff
   a:   bc08        pop {r3}
   c:   bc02        pop {r1}
   e:   4708        bx  r1
```

cortex-a5 specific

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall  -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-a5 -march=armv7-a -c addimm.c -o addimma5.o

00000000 <addimm>:
   0:   b508        push    {r3, lr}
   2:   f7ff fffe   bl  0 <fun>
   6:   f200 1023   addw    r0, r0, #291    ; 0x123
   a:   bd08        pop {r3, pc}
```

cortex-a5 is armv7-a which supports thumb-2 as far as the add immediate itself goes and related to binary size there is no optimization here, 32 bits for thumb and 32 bits for thumb2.  But this is but one example there perhaps will be times that thumb2 produces smaller binaries than thumb.

cortex-m3

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall  -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 -march=armv7-m -c addimm.c -o addimmm3.o

00000000 <addimm>:
   0:   b508        push    {r3, lr}
   2:   f7ff fffe   bl  0 <fun>
   6:   f200 1023   addw    r0, r0, #291    ; 0x123
   a:   bd08        pop {r3, pc}
```

produced the same result as cortex-a5. for this simple example the machine code for this object is the same, same size, when built for cortex-a5 and cortex-m3

Now if I add a bootstrap, a main, and call this function and fill in the function it calls to create a complete, linked, program

```
00000000 <_start>:
   0:   f000 f802   bl  8 <notmain>
   4:   e7fe        b.n 4 <_start+0x4>
    ...

00000008 <notmain>:
   8:   2005        movs    r0, #5
   a:   f000 b801   b.w 10 <addimm>
   e:   bf00        nop

00000010 <addimm>:
  10:   b508        push    {r3, lr}
  12:   f000 f803   bl  1c <fun>
  16:   f200 1023   addw    r0, r0, #291    ; 0x123
  1a:   bd08        pop {r3, pc}

0000001c <fun>:
  1c:   4770        bx  lr
  1e:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
```

We get a result.  The addimm function itself did not change in size.  with a cortex-a5 you have to have some arm code that then switches to thumb, and likely when linking with libraries, etc you may get a mixture of arm and thumb, so

```
00000000 <_start>:
   0:   eb000000    bl  8 <notmain>
   4:   eafffffe    b   4 <_start+0x4>

00000008 <notmain>:
   8:   e92d4008    push    {r3, lr}
   c:   e3a00005    mov r0, #5
  10:   fa000001    blx 1c <addimm>
  14:   e8bd4008    pop {r3, lr}
  18:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

0000001c <addimm>:
  1c:   b508        push    {r3, lr}
  1e:   f000 e804   blx 28 <fun>
  22:   f200 1023   addw    r0, r0, #291    ; 0x123
  26:   bd08        pop {r3, pc}

00000028 <fun>:
  28:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

overall larger binary, the addimm part itself did not change in size though.

as far as linking changing the size of the object, look at this example

bootstrap.s

```
.thumb

.thumb_func
.globl _start
_start:
    bl notmain
hang: b hang

.thumb_func
.globl dummy
dummy:
    bx lr

.code 32
.globl bounce
bounce:
    bx lr
```

hello.c

```
void dummy ( void  );
void bounce ( void  );
void notmain ( void )
{
    dummy();
    bounce();
}
```

looking at an arm build of notmain by itself, the object:

```
00000000 <notmain>:
   0:   e92d4800    push    {fp, lr}
   4:   e28db004    add fp, sp, #4
   8:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <dummy>
   c:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <bounce>
  10:   e24bd004    sub sp, fp, #4
  14:   e8bd4800    pop {fp, lr}
  18:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

depending on what is calling it and what it calls, the linker may have to add more code to deal with items that are defined outside the object, from global variables to external functions

```
00008000 <_start>:
    8000:   f000 f818   bl  8034 <__notmain_from_thumb>

00008004 <hang>:
    8004:   e7fe        b.n 8004 <hang>

00008006 <dummy>:
    8006:   4770        bx  lr

00008008 <bounce>:
    8008:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

0000800c <notmain>:
    800c:   e92d4800    push    {fp, lr}
    8010:   e28db004    add fp, sp, #4
    8014:   eb000003    bl  8028 <__dummy_from_arm>
    8018:   ebfffffa    bl  8008 <bounce>
    801c:   e24bd004    sub sp, fp, #4
    8020:   e8bd4800    pop {fp, lr}
    8024:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00008028 <__dummy_from_arm>:
    8028:   e59fc000    ldr ip, [pc]    ; 8030 <__dummy_from_arm+0x8>
    802c:   e12fff1c    bx  ip
    8030:   00008007    andeq   r8, r0, r7

00008034 <__notmain_from_thumb>:
    8034:   4778        bx  pc
    8036:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
    8038:   eafffff3    b   800c <notmain>
    803c:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

dummy_from_arm and notmain_from_thumb were both added, an increase in the size of the binary.  each object did not change in size but the overall binary did. bounce() was an arm to arm function, no patching,  dummy() arm to thumb  and notmain() thumb to main.

so you might have a cortex-m3 object, and a cortex-a5 object that as far as the code in that object goes they are both identical.  But dopending on what you link them with, which eventually something is dfferent between a cortex-m3 system and a cortex-a5 system, you may see more or less code added by the linker to account for the system differences, libraries, operating system specific, etc even so much as where in the binary you put the object, if it has to have a further reach than it can with a single instruction, then the linker will add even more code.

This is all gcc specific stuff, each toolchain is going to deal with each of these problems in its own way.  It is the nature of the beast when you use an object and linker model, a very good model but the compiler, assembler, and linker have to work together to make sure that global resources can be properly accessed when linked.  has nothing to do with ARM, this problem exists with many/most processor architectures and the toolchains deal with those problems per toolchain, per version, per target architecture.  When I said change the size of the object what I really meant was the linker may add more code to the final binary in order to deal with that object and how it interacts with others.

Comment: Thanks for the extended reply!